# NameError: global name 'QTextBrowser' is not defined

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I found this error at a graphical modeler of QGIS 2.14.4.

When I try to move(drag) some algorithm to a new model,
I saw this message as below:

[image]

Can you explain why this error occurred?

I expect a reinstall will solve this problems, but I want to know why exactly.

---

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
NameError: global name 'QTextBrowser' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerDialog.py", line 94, in _dropEvent
    self._addAlgorithm(alg.getCopy(), event.pos())
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerDialog.py", line 429, in _addAlgorithm
    dlg = ModelerParametersDialog(alg, self.alg)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerParametersDialog.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.setupUi()
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerParametersDialog.py", line 172, in setupUi
    self.txtHelp = QTextBrowser()
NameError: global name 'QTextBrowser' is not defined


파이썬 버전: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS 버전: 2.14.4-Essen Essen, 634f24b 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/bhyu/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/bhyu/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/bhyu/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\bhyu\.qgis2\python\plugins\gearthview\ext-libs
C:\Users\bhyu\.qgis2\python\plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.4\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

Comment: Do you have an old copy of Processing in C:/Users/bhyu/.qgis2/python/plugins? If so, try deleting it and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the fast advice. I tried to do so, but the problem still occured. After reinstalling into QGIS 2.14.8, I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using QGIS 2.14.4. Try updating to 2.18. That file was under [active development.](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commits/master/python/plugins/processing/modeler/ModelerDialog.py) Someone just committed to it yesterday in fact. If 2.18 doesn't solve the problem, try filing a bug.

https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem after reinstalling into QGIS 2.14.8.